# How do you access an HTTP request body in vanilla Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

If you're making a project using vanilla Node.js (i.e. not Express) how do you access the request body (say, for a POST request)?

Tried a bunch of things, but I got this to work:

```
let body = [];
req.on('data', chunk => body.push(chunk));

req.on('end', () => {
    body = JSON.parse(body[0].toString());
    console.log(body); // the actual data
}
```

There's got to be a better way, though, right?

Comment: _"better"_ how, what's the _problem_ with what you've posted?

Comment: This doesn't look correct. Why do you only read the first chunk? You should join all chunks. A HTTP body doesn't have to be in JSON format.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77801794/how-do-you-access-an-http-request-body-in-vanilla-node-js#comment137158084_77801794) E.g., `body = JSON.parse(body[0].toString())` => `body = JSON.parse(body.join(""))` (Assuming the request body is JSON.)

Comment: The "better" way is to use Express middleware, or some other framework -- they contain code like this internally.

Answer (score 0):

Use Readable Stream Events (Manual Parsing):

Gather body chunks using `req.on('data', ...).`

Concatenate chunks on `end` event.
Parse data based on content type (JSON, URL-encoded form data, etc.).

```
let body = [];
req.on('data', chunk => body.push(chunk));

req.on('end', () => {
    let parsedBody;
    if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
        parsedBody = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
    } else if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
        parsedBody = new URLSearchParams(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
    } else {
        // Handle other content types as needed
    }
    console.log(parsedBody);
});
```